# Form doesn't submit without refresh (please Vanilla JS only)

Tags: javascript

I know this is a bit tricky because I can't actually post the JS or HTML code but I'll try my best to describe it.

So basically I created a table with JS on the HTML. 
Then I use "submit" and "form" in the html to submit content onto the table. The content is retrieved with fetch and an API.

The issue I have is that while it all works well, the data doesn't appear on the table without me having to refresh the browser. I'd the data to appear as soon as I click the submit button.

Cheers and thanks in advance

Comment: Apparently you're running some sort of a routine on page load to generate the HTML for the table. Sounds like you need to rerun that routine after the form submit to regenerate the table. Anything more than that, I'm afraid you're going to have to post some code.

Answer (score 0):

Its obvious and correct to dont show new records because table just can show last result of request .
For your goal you can reload just table tag with ajax or other ways for example you can refresh table tag x second after click on submit button.(x should be enough big that new records has time to submit).